# Hololens emulator mouse input not captured

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

In Hololens Emulator with Windows 10 Pro, I can only use keyboard strokes and my mouse is not recognized. How can I turn on mouse input? I did nothing to connect my keyboard, so why is it with a mouse that I have to change something?

Comment: in what context would you want to use the mouse? Can you give an example?

Comment: @AlexDrenea It was an issue with my Hyper-V.. I'll delete this question in a bit. Basically, I wanted to be able to "look around" in my emulator using mouse input.

Comment: could you explain what the issue with Hyper-V was? i'm having the same problem

Comment: @iedoc I recently restarted the emulator and have the issue again. I will post when I figure out the details of my solution and let you know!

Comment: @iedoc there we go. check the answers. turns out it wasn't hyper-v...

Comment: @mpappu I found out the issue for me was something to do with the network setup for hyper-v. If i bridge the network in hyper-v to my ethernet, it works fine, but i lose internet. I had somehow solved it after i commented above, but i'm not sure exactly what it was that solved it

Comment: @iedoc I've been having troubles with the network as well. you use ethernet you said, have you tried using wifi to have internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem that may solve it: make sure when using the emulator that in Package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio the MaxVersionTested line is the correct version. I was looking at an older version which everyone says to use: 10.0.10586.0 which was incorrect. When choosing the device for debugging, the version will be in the name. Currently, the most updated version (that I am using) is 10.0.14342.1018. After that, start debugging and run the emulator and you should have keyboard and mouse input!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I'm not sure how I solved it. Here is what I have done:

<s>Installed Update 3 for VS 2015. Tried again without restarting the PC and got the same problem.  On the next day I started the HoloLens Emulator directly via Hyper-V Manager. After that I started my project in Visual Studio. The Emulator loaded correctly and now the Human Input and Keyboard and Mouse Input buttons are enabled.</s>

Update: That was definitely not the answer, but I found a working solution here:
http://forums.hololens.com/discussion/952/no-input-from-emulator

Just put off your proxy in IE and the icons will be enabled. I could turn my proxy on again and the controls remained active.